# How do you merge two unequal input/list in Python3

Tags: python, python-3.5

sorry if my formatting is wrong as this is my first time posting here. I'm completely new to Python3 so my question may seems very basic. I've posted the inputs and the output below.

```
Input1: James Ryan

Input2: John Becky William Isaac

Output: James John Ryan Becky William Isaac
```

**My code currently**

```
Enter1 = input('').split()
Enter2 = input('').split()
Enter3 = (' ').join(x for i in zip(Enter1, Enter2) 
for x in i)
print(Enter3)
```

My current code is giving me the following:

```
Input1: James Ryan

Input2: John Becky William Isaac

Output: James John Ryan Becky
```

I don't exactly know what I need to do to achieve the right output.

Comment: `Enter3 = Enter1 + Enter2`

Comment: Does the ordering you specified in the output matter? If so, just adding the lists together won't give you that result, no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why most of the answers have `list1+list2` as it will just append the list(s) which is not the expected output. You can try something as below. Taking order from your example provided where one element is from smaller list and other from the bigger list.

```
input1='John Becky William Isaac'
input2='James Ryan'
input1=input1.split(' ')
input2=input2.split(' ')
new=[]

max_list,min_list=(input1,input2) if len(input1)>len(input2) else (input2,input1)

for i in range(len(min_list)):
    new.append(min_list[i]+' '+max_list[i])
new += max_list[len(min_list):]
print(' '.join(new)) # James John Ryan Becky William Isaac
```

Answer (score 2):

```
from itertools import zip_longest

name3 = list(zip_longest(name1.split(), name2.split(), fillvalue = ''))
print(' '.join([j for i in name3 for j in i]))
```

> ```
> James John Ryan Becky  William  Isaac
> ```

If you want to use zip here its going to have to be `zip_longest` due to the uneven sizes of the the two

Answer (score 0):

This is just elaborating on Arihant's answer :

```
Enter3 = Enter1 + Enter2
for all in Enter3:
    print(all)
```

If you want to save it as a variable:

```
output = []
for all in Enter3:
   output.append(all)
string_output = " ".join(output)
print(string_output)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to extend the smaller list to make it same size as the other.

```
delta = ans(len(Enter1) - len(Enter2))
lst_to_append = [''] * delta

if len(Enter1) < len(Enter2):
    Enter1.extend(lst_to_append)
else:
    Enter2.extend(lst_to_append)
```

Use your code for Enter3 as it is.